# Importing declarations from another file with as little repetition as possible?

Tags: typescript

I have moved declarations into a separate file to keep my files shorter. Below is how I import them.

**client-types.ts**

```
declare module 'client-types' {
    export interface IRequestBody { type: 'request' }
    export interface CreateProjectRequestBody extends IRequestBody { cmd: 'otii_create_project' }
    export interface GetArcsRequestBody extends IRequestBody { cmd: 'otii_get_devices' }
    export interface OpenProjectRequestBody extends IRequestBody { cmd: 'otii_open_project', payload: { value: string, force: boolean, progress: boolean } }

    export interface IResponse {}
    export interface CreateProjectResponse extends IResponse { payload: { project_id: number } }
    export interface GetArcsResponse extends IResponse { payload: { devices: [ { device_id: number, name: string, type: string } ] } }
    export interface OpenProjectResponse extends IResponse { payload: { project_id: string } }

    export interface ResponseDevice { device_id: number, name: string, type: string }

    export interface CreateProjectResponseData { id: number }
    export interface GetArcsResponseData { [index: number]: {id: number, name: string} }
    export interface OpenProjectResponseData { id: number }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
// imports
import { 
    IRequestBody, 
    CreateProjectRequestBody, 
    GetArcsRequestBody, 
    OpenProjectRequestBody,
    IResponse,
    CreateProjectResponse,
    GetArcsResponse,
    OpenProjectResponse,
    ResponseDevice,
    CreateProjectResponseData,
    GetArcsResponseData,
    OpenProjectResponseData
} from 'client-types';

// use
request(body: CreateProjectRequestBody) : Promise<CreateProjectResponse>
request(body: GetArcsRequestBody) : Promise<GetArcsResponse>
request(body: OpenProjectRequestBody) : Promise<OpenProjectResponse>
request<T extends IRequestBody>(body: T): Promise<IResponse> {
    ...
}

async createProject() : Promise<CreateProjectResponseData> { 
    ...
}
```

I dislike having to write every type in the import statement. I would prefer something like the following:

```
import * from from 'client-types';
```

but then I get the error `[ts] 'as' expected.`

Is there a way to remove this repetition (as it feels to me) or am I already using "best practice"?

PS: The code I am writing will become an npm package. Let me know if you think there  is anything npm specific I should be aware of in relation to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
import * as clientTypes from 'client-types';
```

Then use `clientTypes.CreateProjectRequestBody` instead of `CreateProjectRequestBody`, etc.

But a good IDE should automatically import the types as you write them.

See also: [ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/).

Comment: I would like that, but without having to prefix every use with clientTypes :-) But if there is no other way, then your response will be the correct one.

Comment: @user1283776 I confirm there is no other way.